# Android Canvas.drawCircle in the center of the screen

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am using `Canvas.drawCircle` to draw a circle in Android laout.

Method gets 3 parameters - first two are position - `x` and `y`.

Is it possible to skip hardcoded position of the circle and draw it centered ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Following code can be used to get the width and height of the screen.

```
int width = this.getWidth(); 
int height = this.getHeight();
```

To draw circle in the middle of screen you can call :

```
Canvas.drawCircle(width/2, height/2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are extending the View class:

```
int CentreX = (this.getWidth() / 2);
int CentreY = (this.getHeight() / 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can paint a circle centered to the screen like this:

```
Display disp = ((WindowManager)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
canvas.drawCircle(disp.getWidth()/2, disp.getHeight()/2, radius, paint);
```

Comment: `Display#getWidth()` and `Display#getHeight()` are deprecated.